# JavaScript error" Cannot read properties of undefined" when dealing with a game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a card rpg game and while most of it is complete, I am running into an TypeError while trying to get attributes from the enemy. When I click the Attack button, the speeds are supposed to be read from enemy and player, then whomever is greater gets to attack first. But I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'speed')
    at Object.calcAttack (Player.js:18:28)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):34:64)
calcAttack @ Player.js:18
onclick @ (index):34
```

Index.HTML

```
  <button onclick="playerMoves.calcAttack()">Attack!
        </button>
```

Player.JS

```
let player;

function Player(level, health, attack, speed, magic, experience){
    this.level = level;
    this.health = health;
    this.attack = attack;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.magic = magic;
    this.experience = experience;
};




    let playerMoves =  {
    calcAttack: function(){

    //Attacking sequence, getting player and enemy speed to see whose fastests and what will happen after the first attack
    let playerSpeed = player.speed;
    let enemySpeed = enemy.speed;

    console.log(playerSpeed, enemySpeed);
    
    if (playerSpeed >= enemySpeed){
    enemy.health = enemy.health - outputDmg;

    if(enemy.health <= 0){
        alert("You have defeated the enemy!");
        //functin to load more enemies
    } else{
        player.health = player.health - outputEnemyDmg;

        if(player.health <= 0){
            alert("You have died")
        }

    };

}
```

The enemy speed is in a separate file called Enemy.JS

```
function Enemy(rank, name, imgName, health, attack, speed, droppedExp){
    this.rank = rank;
    this.name = name;
    this.imgName = imgName;
    this.health = health;
    this.attack = attack;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.droppedExp = droppedExp;
};


//Ranking will go from E, ,D C, B, A, S and follow 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

let goblin = new Enemy(1,"Goblin", "goblin", 50, 5, 10, 10);
let raikan = new Enemy(1, "Steel Fanged Raikan", "raikan", 50, 5, 10, 10);
let briga = new Enemy(1, "Razor Claw Briga", "briga", 55, 15, 10, 10);
let centipede = new Enemy(2 ,"Giant Desert Centipede", "centipede", 100, 15, 5, 20);
let jackal = new Enemy(2, "Dungeon Jackal", "jackal", 75, 10, 15, 20);
```

Comment: It looks like `let playerSpeed = player.speed;` does not work because your `player` variable is undefined. Where do you set a value to that variable?

Comment: It gets set in another file gameplay.js; this works fine and I am able to get the player variables, however the error comes from the enemy.speed

Comment: Can you add code for how you are defining the enemy variable in PlayerJS? @AlejandroGarciaBaltazar